# Трудности с установкой HSQLDB

Tags: база-данных, установка, настройка

Здравствуйте!
В данный момент я работаю над небольшим веб-приложением в java с использованием СУБД HSQLDB. Однако у меня возникли трудности при установке и настройке этой СУБД.

Выполняю все действия поэтапно, как написано в [официальной пошаговой инструкции](http://www.programmingforfuture.com/2010/06/using-hypersql-hsqldb.html), но на этапе прописывания путей в cmd (как указано в пункте **Running database**) возникает ошибка вида:
`"hsqldb" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.`

На мой взгляд оно и не могло быть иначе т.к. это portable СУБД и собственно даже если задать путь к корневой папке СУБД в переменных среды, то ничего не изменится ибо исполняемого файла нет.

Объясните, пожалуйста, как все-таки установить и настроить HSQLDB в соответствии с инструкцией и что мне сделать чтобы это было возможно. Ведь я даже не пойму в чем дело.

Спасибо заранее!

P.S. Обязательно прочитайте официальную инструкцию по установке, чтобы понять о чем речь - ссылка выше в тексте.
P.P.S. Командную строку запускаю с правами администратора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы отклонились от инструкции, по всей видимости. Но вы не виноваты в этом. Там есть сбивающий с толку момент:

```
hsqldb>set path=%path%;D://program files/java/jdk1.6.0_13/bin
```

`hsqldb>` не является частью этой команды. Это исключительно маркер того, что команда выполняется в рабочей папке `hsqldb`. Этот маркер выводится самим интерпретатором `cmd` и вводить его не нужно.

Сама команда чуточку короче:

```sh
set path=%path%;D://program files/java/jdk1.6.0_13/bin
```

Убедиться в правильности написания можно, посмотрев там же на скриншот результата:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хорошо, допустим, а как мне сделать, чтобы команда выводилась в рабочей папке hsqldb? У меня маркер вида C:\Users\userName>

Comment: @IngeniousTom Нужно перейти в ту папку, куда распаковали hsqldb, где находятся обозначенные в инструкции файлы.

Comment: Как туда перейти в консоли cmd? В проводнике эта папка итак у меня открыта

Comment: @IngeniousTom `cd диск:\папка1\папка2\папка3`

Comment: Я написал cd D:\hsqldb-2.3.3\hsqldb, в результате слева от маркера все так же  написано C:\Windows\system32> Что я мог написать неправильно?

Comment: @IngeniousTom а, аж на другом диске. Тогда сначала надо отдельно сменить диск (`D:`), а потом выполнить эту команду снова.

Comment: Спасибо большое - уже половина дела сделана. Сменить директорию, прописать путь мне удалось успешно. Теперь я создал как в инструкции файл свойств сервера server.properties с тем содержимым, что указано в инструкции, скопировав его туда и сохранил. Естественно в формате txt ибо в инструкции про формат ничего нет. Но видимо это неправильный формат раз следующая команда в инструкции через cmd не выполняется, жалуясь что не может загрузить файл свойств сервера. Как думаете, что тут можно сделать?

Comment: @IngeniousTom **следовать инструкции**. Строго. Очень. "Now prepare a file named `server.properties`". Никаких `.txt`.

Comment: Понял - мой косяк. Спрасибо за объяснение. Дальше сам разберусь. Ставлю оценку вам. +1